# Field does not exist in model "res.config.settings"

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I would like to add configuration for a custom Odoo module. However, whenever I try to install the module, I get the following error. It seems that the custom model that I create is not being seen by Odoo.

```
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view near:

                            <div class="o_setting_search">
                                <input type="text" class="searchInput pull-right p-0 pb-1" placeholder="Search..."/>
                                <span class="searchIcon"><i class="fa fa-search" role="img" aria-label="Search" title="Search"/></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Field "test_field" does not exist in model "res.config.settings"
```

`./models/__init__.py`

```
from . import res_config_settings
```

`./models/res_config_settings.py`

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"
    _name = "test.settings"

    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field")

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and res.update(
            test_field=test_config.test_field,
        )
        return res

    def set_values(self):
        super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and test_config.write({
            'test_field': self.test_field,
        })
```

`views/settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.test</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('settings')]" position="inside">
        <div
          class="app_settings_block"
          data-string="Abcdefg Test Configuration"
          string="Abcdefg Test Configuration"
          data-key="odoo-abcdefg-test-module"
        >
          <h2>Test Configuration</h2>
          <group>
            <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container">
              <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                <label for="test_field" string="Test Field"/>
                <field name="test_field"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </group>
        </div>
      </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

`__init__.py`

```
from . import models
```

`__manifest__.py`

```
{
    "name": "ABCDEFG Test Module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "category": "Testing",
    "application": False,
    "installable": True,
    "depends": ["base"],
    "data": [
        "views/settings.xml",
    ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You combined  `_name` with `inherit` attribute which will result in a new model named `test.settings`. It's called [Classical inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#classical-inheritance).

To add the `test_field` to `res.config.settings` just remove the `_name` attribute.

Comment: Just as additional information: in now very old Odoo versions it was just normal to create new setting models. But with the big change to one big settings menu, that normal became to not working anymore. So yes in newer versions just inherit `res.config.settings` in an extension way.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Removing the `_name` attribute from the model *does* allow me to install the module without an error and I even see the Test Field text input field shown on the Settings page. However, when I fill in a value and click save, the value does not seem to be saved since when I refresh the page, the value is no longer filled in the input field. Should I change the `set_values` method on the model? What should I do differently?

Comment: You use the `config_parameter` field attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```html
from odoo import api, fields, models


class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"

    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field")

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and res.update(
            test_field=test_config.test_field,
        )
        return res

    def set_values(self):
        super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and test_config.write({
            'test_field': self.test_field,
        })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think your solution will work and why the original solution wasn't working?

Comment: @CZoellner. I think you miss something. I am the one who answered first. But I agree with his solution.

Comment: No i don't miss anything but an explanation why your code example should work. I know it's the same solution like in the later answer, but "try this" is not enough for me to upvote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error in odoo Missing field string information for the field 'module_website_hr_recruitment' from the 'res.config.settings' model

all i did was to install the Recruitment module in odoo and it worked