# Custom fields on res.config.settings not saved

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I would like to add configuration for a custom Odoo module. However, when I fill in a value for the setting `test_field` and click save, the value does not seem to be saved since when I refresh the page, the value is no longer filled in the input field. Should I change the `set_values` method on the model? What should I do differently?

This is a follow-up question to this one: [Field does not exist in model "res.config.settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176276/field-does-not-exist-in-model-res-config-settings).

`./models/__init__.py`

```
from . import res_config_settings
```

`./models/res_config_settings.py`

```
from odoo import api, fields, models


class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"

    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field")

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and res.update(
            test_field=test_config.test_field,
        )
        return res

    def set_values(self):
        super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        test_config = self.env.ref('test_config', False)
        test_config and test_config.write({
            'test_field': self.test_field,
        })
```

`views/settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.test</field>
    <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('settings')]" position="inside">
        <div
          class="app_settings_block"
          data-string="Abcdefg Test Configuration"
          string="Abcdefg Test Configuration"
          data-key="odoo-abcdefg-test-module"
        >
          <h2>Test Configuration</h2>
          <group>
            <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container">
              <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                <label for="test_field" string="Test Field"/>
                <field name="test_field"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </group>
        </div>
      </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

`__init__.py`

```
from . import models
```

`__manifest__.py`

```
{
    "name": "ABCDEFG Test Module",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "category": "Testing",
    "application": False,
    "installable": True,
    "depends": ["base"],
    "data": [
        "views/settings.xml",
    ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

From [ResConfigSettings](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_config.py#L342) source code documentation:

- For a field with no specific prefix BUT an attribute `config_parameter`,
  `execute` will save its value in an `ir.config.parameter` (global setting for the
  database).
- For the other fields, the method `execute` invokes `set_values`. Override it to implement the effect of those fields.

You can override the `set_values` to save the `test_field` value in `ir.config_parameter` table like they did in [auth_password_policy](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/auth_password_policy/models/res_config_settings.py#L4) module

***Example:***

```py
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"

    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field")

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        res['test_field'] = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param("base.test_field", default="")
        return res

    @api.model
    def set_values(self):
        self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param("base.test_field", self.test_field or '')
        super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
```

Or simply using the `config_parameter` field attribute

***Example***:

```
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"

    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field", config_parameter='base.test_field')
```